# Lightblue Bean BTLE tinkering

Tags: bluetooth, atmega328

How does one modify the Bluetooth settings, like services or pincode, on a light blue bean?
Ps I'm on Android

http://legacy.punchthrough.com/bean/ if you don't know what I'm talking about